# Elements corresponding to conditions in a sublist in Python

Tags: python, list

I have lists `J` and `cond1`. I want to print the values in `J` corresponding to `False` in each sublist of `cond1`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
J=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4]]
cond1=[[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, True]]]

result = [value for value, condition in zip(J, cond1) if not condition]
print(result)
```

The current output is

```
[]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1,4, 7],[1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a old but gold for loop. there might be more elegant solutions, but if the two lists are small, it can be totally fine ..

```
J = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4]]
cond1 = [[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, True]]]

for j, c in zip(J, cond1):
    values = [x for x, y in zip(j, c[0]) if not y]
    print(values)
```

this returns

```
[1, 4, 7]
[1]
```

The expected result from the user cannot be correct, element '7' is False as well. Am I missing something ?

Comment: This doesn't yield the expected output.

Comment: I edited the code, recheck please

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the lists in `cond1` are nested inside another list, whereas in `J` they are at the top level. This is what's causing the confusion.
If you were to fix the nesting everything works, as seen here:

```
J=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4]]
cond1=[[False, True, False, True, False], [False, True]]
# note that J and cond1 have the same nesting level here

def retain_false(numbers, booleans):
    return [num for num, boolean in zip(numbers, booleans) if not boolean]

for numbers, booleans in zip(J, cond1):
    print(retain_false(numbers, booleans))

## output
[1, 4, 7]
[1]
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to handle the nesting issue, then just access the first index of `booleans`:

```
for numbers, booleans in zip(J, cond1):
    print(retain_false(numbers, booleans[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

According your question, the expected output should to be `[[1,4,7],[1]]`

This match your requirement:

```py
J=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4]]
cond1=[[[False, True, False, True, False]], [[False, True]]]

values = [[x for x, y in zip(j, c[0]) if not y] for j, c in zip(J, cond1)]
print(values)
```